# Laravel not showing image from public storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am working on a Laravel 6 project.
Laravel's default folder structure has been modified to look like this:

All of laravel's files are in this folder

```
/var/www/laravel/releases/2022-01-07/
```

The storage folder has been moved to

```
/var/www/laravel/storage
                |-- app
                    |-- logs
                    |-- public
                        |-- images
                        |-- logs
                |-- debugbar
                |-- framework
                |-- logs
```

A symlink has been created:

```
ln -nfs "/var/www/laravel/storage" "/var/www/laravel/releases/2022-01-07/storage"
```

The `filesystems.php` file has the disk specified as:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

I can upload files just fine through my UI, using `$request->uploadedImage->store('images', 'public');`. The image file is being place in `/var/www/laravel/storage/app/public/images/`. However, after navigating to the view which is supposed to grab the image, the file is not found.
In the blade file, using `{{ asset('storage/'.$image) }}` results in `https://example.com/storage/images/filename.jpg`, which results in 404; not found.

What are some things I should be checking? At this time, I just feel lost.
I have been fiddling around with different permissions, unfortunately without any success. The `laravel/releases/` folder belongs to `deployer:deployer`, while the `laravel/storage` folder belongs to `www-data:www-data`, which doesn't seem to be an issue during upload, so I am not sure if this would be an issue upon retrieving the file? The uploaded image itself belongs to `www-data:www-data`.

Thank you very much for taking the time to reading through this issue.

Comment: Just change the APP_URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link between *storage* to *public* as only the later is designed for safe access. Try to execute *php artisan storage:link* In your Laravel project folder.

More details, please refer https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: I thought `php artisan storage:link` would just create a symlink, right? The symlink has already been created though and is working fine, as I am able to upload to said folder.

Comment: Please make sure the path 'project_root/storage/images/filename.jpg' is correct. Your image name should be a hashed string by default after being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem like that. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it and I tried everything. The solution I used was to retrieve the files via download since I was not able to display files in a view.

In routes:

```
Route::get('download/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CandidateController@filedownload')->middleware(['auth'])->name('file.download');
```

In controller:

```
public function filedownload($id)
{
    try {
        $candidate = Candidate::find($id);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return abort(403, $e);
    }
    return Storage::download($cadidate->document_file);
}
```

In view:

```
<tr style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">
   <td>
      <a class="link" href="{{ route('file.download', [$candidate->id]) }}">Download</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```